# generate random vector in R based on values of other vectors, probability

Tags: r, conditional-statements

given the following:

```
N = 100
v = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), N/4)
```

I would like to create some vector `x` such that `x = 1` with probability conditional on `v`

So we would have

```
P(x = 1 | v = 'a') = 0.8
P(x = 1 | v = 'b') = 0.6
P(x = 1 | v = 'c') = 0.4
P(x = 1 | v = 'd') = 0.1
```

`x` should only have values `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using `rbinom`:

```
set.seed(2020)
N <- 10000
probs <- rep(c(a=.8, b=.6, c=.4, d=.1), N/4)
v <- rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), N/4)
x <- sapply(probs, function(u) {rbinom(n = 1, size = 1, prob = u)})
tapply(x, v, mean)

     a      b      c      d 
0.8048 0.6024 0.3896 0.0904
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sample from a uniform distribution and then compare it to your cutoffs to generate such values. For example

```
probs <- c(a=.8, b=.6, c=.4, d=.1)
x <- runif(N) < probs[v]
```

For example, with a larger number of samples, we can see we get roughly the proportions we expect

```
set.seed(11)
N = 1000
v = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), N/4)
probs <- c(a=.8, b=.6, c=.4, d=.1)
x <- runif(N) < probs[v]
tapply(x, v, mean)
#     a     b     c     d 
# 0.780 0.604 0.376 0.120
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not really need the letters. Just use the probabilities:

```
set.seed(42)
N <- 100
v <- rep(c(.8, .6, .4, .1), N/4)
(x <- rbinom(100, 1, v))
#   [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
#  [38] 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
#  [75] 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
```

This gives the proportion of 1s for each group as compared with your targets (.8, .6, .4, .1):

```
rowSums(matrix(x, 4, 25))/25
# [1] 0.76 0.64 0.36 0.16
```